# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'PAY_0.1' not found (Boosting)

Tags: r, r-caret, training-data, kaggle, boosting

I am trying to apply a boosting model but I keep getting this error. Any help at all would be much appreciated. This is a data set from kaggle, UCI credit card data, if you are wondering.

```r
DataSplit <- createDataPartition(UCIdata$default.payment.next.month, 
                                 p=.8,list=FALSE)
boosttrain <- UCIdata[DataSplit, ]
boosttest <- UCIdata[-DataSplit, ]
gmbGrid2 <- expand.grid(maxdepth = seq(1,10,1), iter = 50, nu = seq(0.1, 1, 0.1))
boostingcontrol2 <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                                 classProbs = TRUE, 
                                 summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)
gmbFit2 <- train(default.payment.next.month~., data = boosttrain[, 2:25],
                 method = "ada", trControl = boostingcontrol2, 
                 verbose = FALSE, tuneGrid = gmbGrid2)
```

I then get this out.

> Warning messages:
> 1: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
> The metric "Accuracy" was not in the result set. ROC will be used instead.
> 2: In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
> predictions failed for Fold01.Rep1: nu=0.1, maxdepth= 1, iter=50 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'PAY_0.1' not found

In the data set there is no `PAY_0.1`, only `PAY_0`, `PAY_2`, `PAY_3`,...,`PAY_6`. Where could the `PAY_0.1` come from?

Comment: Ah here whats with the voting down? I am quite new to R, give me a break oiiiii oi

Answer (score 1):

I guess PAY_0 is a binary/factor variable in your dataset. PAY_0.1 is dummy variable created from expansion of this variable which is PAY_0.0 and PAY_0.1 . More than likely PAY_0 have very few 1s so PAY_0.1 will have very few 1's. When doing training along with CV (repeatedcv) it is possible that one of the fold might not have got any 1's and hence this error. Or probably when you are building tree of depth 1 then no tree have breakage based on PAY_0.1 variable.

To correct the problem please do:

1. start your depth range a bit high. So instead of `maxdepth=seq(1,10,1)` if you use `maxdepth=seq(4,10,1)` you might not get this problem. Depth 1 tree is too shallow.
2. Check the distribution of PAY_0. If there are too less 1's then you can do upsampling of 1's or downsampling of 0's.